# Show Gridview Template Header Text as DataList value in Header

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl_company" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="5"
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="4" >
 <ItemTemplate>
         <h2>
          <asp:Label ID="lbl_domain" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_letter")%>'></asp:Label>
        </h2>               
 </ItemTemplate>

 <asp:GridView ID="dg1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText= "" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#E5E5E5" 
                        HeaderStyle-Height="20px"  ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("PERSISTED")%>
        </ItemTemplate>                                                                        
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
private void grddatabinding()
    {
        DataTable dt = new Code.User().getcdomain();
        dl_company.DataSource = dt;
        dl_company.DataBind();

        for (int i = 0; i < dl_company.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lbl_domain = (Label)dl_company.Items[i].FindControl("lbl_domain");
            DataTable dt2 = new Code.User().getcompanycard(lbl_domain.Text);
            if (dt2.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                GridView dg1 = (GridView)dl_company.Items[i].FindControl("dg1");
                dg1.DataSource = dt2;
                dg1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

How i can get Gridview Header Text as = `Label Value (lbl_domain)`

A to Z is DataList Label Value

Gridview Gives me List of domains alphabeticall i.e

"A" DataList Label
Blank(Header)   Gridview
apple.com
arkk.com

same for alphabet starting with B till Z

I need like this

--"A"   (DataList Label -- Not this)

"A" Gridview Like this - Template Header (But Value should from DataList)
apple.com
arkk.com